# How to find basis of sum of two subspace of $M_{2,2}$ with algebraic elements

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V=M_{2,2}(\mathbb{R})$ and let
$W_1=\{
\begin{pmatrix}
x & -x\\
y & z
\end{pmatrix}
: x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}
\}$
and
$W_2=\{
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
-a & c
\end{pmatrix}
: a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}
\}$
Find a basis for $W_1$ + $W_2$

Knowing that $dim(V)=4$ and $W_1+W_2 = span(V)$ and the sum can be expressed as
$V = \begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{pmatrix}=
x\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+
y\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}+
z\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}+
a\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix}+
b\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+
c\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$

Does the basis have to be four matrices with x,y,b,c in matrix form?

Can the basis consist of three or less matrix and how do u find such basis?

Comment: Find the basis of $W_1$ and $W_2$ and put them into a matrix and rref it.

Comment: @K.Y can such basis be expressed in three or less matrices?

Comment: You should check that among of that spanning vectors,, which are linearly independent,,,

Comment: Best things of doing such case, first find the basis for W₁ and W₂, then try to find such vectors in W₁ that are in linear combination of the vectors of the basis of W₂,also this thing can be done for the basis elements of W₂ that they are spanned by basis elements of W₁. Then you can eliminate such vectors for finding the basis elements for W₁+W₂.